# Adding a document number as a first line in \documentclass{article}

Tags: titles

I would like to add a document name in a small font,  as a very first line of the title page inside the article environment, something like:

---

> ```
> review of project number: 1234
>
>                                 Title
>                                Author
> ```

Comment: Please clarify a little more. Where do you exactly want to put the number? What kind of number? Any global relation with other documents you produce? And welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Do you want it in the header on the first page or in the text area or elsewhere?

Answer (score 5):

Another approach would be the use of the `titling` package, since I have no skills to patch LaTeX commands: `:)`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titling}

\newcommand{\review}[1]{%
\pretitle{%
\begin{flushleft}
review of project number: #1
\end{flushleft}
\vspace{1em}
\begin{center}\LARGE}
\posttitle{\par\end{center}\vskip 0.5em}
}

\review{1234}
\title{My title}
\author{The author}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

and the output:

[image]

There we go. `:)`

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean something like this?

> [image]

Code (I've patched `\@maketitle` and `\maketitle` to not insert `\newpage`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{\newpage}{\relax}{}{}
\patchcmd{\maketitle}{\newpage}{\relax}{}{}
\makeatother

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{}

\begin{document}

{\noindent\small review of project number: 1234}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```